# Select Row from GridView

Tags: asp.net, list, gridview

how i can select Row from GridView without DataKey ?

I have a Grid view with data source from List and i need when 
press select select Get the selected row ?

```
List<string> RequestedMovie = new List<string>();
GridView3.Datasource = RequestedMovie;
```

Comment: What have you tried? Have you googled this as it is a pretty basic thing to select a row from a GridView.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly get the selected row by using the following line of code

```
  GridViewRow objRow = GridView3.SelectedRow;
  ..
  ..
```

I hope that will resolve your problem.